# Combine and Redirecting stderr and stdin - Difference in Methods BASH

Tags: bash, shell

What is the real difference of the **new** and the **old** methods of how we combine and redirect stderr and stdin?

For example:

- "The Old Way": `2>&1`
- "The New Way": `&>`

Down to the core are there any differences in these implementations?
Are their any advantages to either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the "new way" is a bashism. It's not POSIX.

My advice is avoid bashisms & write POSIX shell as best as you can. And least then you stand a chance of it working on other (faster) shell implementations.

- [Related tool checkbashisms](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/devscripts.git/plain/scripts/checkbashisms.pl)